# How to place menu items on a curved bar?

Tags: html, css, laravel, svg

My client wants a curved menu. How can I do it? Menu items are in red squares, and they should be roughly where pink squares are (on the blue bar).

Should I somehow place them in the SVG or combine SVG with the background image and position the menu items with flexbox and so on?

And it should also be a bit responsive to about 1000px width. From there I'll transition the menu to the mobile version, that I already have for other pages.

Comment: Stll, you might want to show us your previous attempts, and the relevant parts of your existing code. You could even setup an example on codepen.io or similiar to provide the SVG you're talking about, instead of just showing a _picture_ of it. And as @Paulie_D has already mentioned, you also might want to do some additional research like [having text follow a SVG path](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/curved-text-along-path/) and share it with the people you're expecting help from.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <body height="100%" width="100%">
    <svg height="100%" width="100%" viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
         <path d="M 10 10 Q 50 50 90 50 v -40 h -80" fill="cyan" transform="scale(1.05,1.05) translate(-4.5,-.5)"/>
      <path id="path" d="M 10 10 Q 50 50 90 50" fill="none" stroke="yellow"/>
      <text font-size="4">
        <textPath href="#path" textPath="stretch">
          <tspan dx="5">Alternative1</tspan>
          <tspan dx="10">Alternative2</tspan>
          <tspan dx="10">Alternative3</tspan>
        </textPath>
        
        
      </text>
     
      
   
      
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a goo alternative indeed, but not quite what the client desires. Thank you either way for your time! (might help others)

Comment: Perhaps if you want help you should explain in greater detail exactly what kind of effect you are trying to acomplish.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and reliable way to do this is to measure every rectangle's position from the left and top of the picture and measure the width and height of the picture too.

It doesn't matter what units you use for this - as long as it's the same one for each one.

Then you have a series of top/left offsets and can get CSS to work out the % positioning of each one from the left, top of the picture.

Then for each li:nth-child(n) set put in the 2 CSS variables: --left: x; --top: y; that you measured and in the ul --w: ; --h:

Then position the nth-child as a % from the top left of the image using CSS calc.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this one out too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Every idea is welcome, even the bad ones.

Here is a bad one; if you really do **not** want to calculate/hardcode X,Y positions.

Using keyPoints to position the `<text>` element on a path

Set `dur="0s"` if you don't want the animation

```html
<style>
  svg{
    width:90vw;
    background:pink;
  }
</style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 50">
  <path id="slope" fill="none" stroke="red" d="m10,10c40,0,45,35,180,35"></path>
  <text>One
    <animateMotion dur="1s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;.1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear">
      <mpath href="#slope"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </text>
  <text>Two
    <animateMotion dur="1s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;.4" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear">
      <mpath href="#slope"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </text>
  <text>Three
    <animateMotion dur="1s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;.75" keyTimes="0;1"calcMode="linear">
      <mpath href="#slope"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the screenshot you provided there were a few ways you could tackle this. The difficulty really depends on how you are implementing the background graphic as if this is background image when you resize then the offset needed on each navigation item will differ slightly.

Here are two of the simplest solutions.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 20px;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  top: 40px;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  top: 50px;
}
li:nth-child(5), li:nth-child(6), li:nth-child(7), li:nth-child(8) {
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' title=''>Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The first solution is the laziest, you could simply just offset your items using nth-child - this would be significantly tidier if you were using SCSS since you could throw it in an iterator.( ultimately the compiled code would come out looking similar to the above ) The downside to this method is to make it truly responsive you would likely need to add a few media queries at various sizes to match up the background curve with the links

And the javascript approach :-

```js
let endingCurve = 80;
let currentCurve = 0;
let navItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
let offsetPerItem = (endingCurve / navItems.length);
navItems.forEach(item => {
  currentCurve = currentCurve + offsetPerItem
  item.style.top = `${currentCurve}px`;
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='' title=''>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='' title=''>Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

you define an ending curve, count the number of items you have in your navigation structure and divide the total by the curve, this works out the general offset per item, you then loop through each item and apply a `top` style to each item. This is pretty much a javascript version of nth-child with the added bonus that you can change the `endingCurve` value to increase or decrease the "curve".

There are much more elegant javascript solutions you could create if given more information .e.g is the background image curve fixed, does it scale with the browser, is it an svg or another format, etc.. But this should give you a starting point either way!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give it a go and see from there.