# How to create a clickable circle of svg images

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I've got a few svg files that all fit together like a puzzle and together form a circle. What is the best way to position them? I've tried Creating an `ul` and put the segments in it, all on top of eachother. Since the segment svgs are already rotated correctly I thought I could just put display flex on the wrapper, and put a gap between them, but gap does not seem to work.

My code now:

```
<div class="expertises-wrap">
    <ul class="expertises">
        <li>
            <img class="slice" src="img/infographic/techniek.svg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="slice" src="img/infographic/aard-warmte-projecten.svg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="slice" src="img/infographic/duurzame-energiezaken.svg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="slice" src="img/infographic/modellering.svg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="slice" src="img/infographic/ruimtelijke-ontwikkeling.svg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="slice" src="img/infographic/corporate-finance.svg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img class="slice" src="img/infographic/makelaardij.svg">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(S)CSS

```
.expertises {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    gap: 70px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    li {
        position:absolute;
        img{
            width: 250px;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to approach this?

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fyL4r0vu/

Desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the live example?

Comment: @AnasAnsari I've added a js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fyL4r0vu/ Not all images work, just a few added as example.

Comment: Please add the desired outcome - your title is talking about clicking but your asking about positioning, not sure what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @0stone0 Added image

Comment: Only the first 3 images working please correct the path of the rest images

Comment: you have to set the position of images by using top, left, right properties

Comment: Can you post all the pieces? Moet makkelijker te doen zijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using an SVG as a wrapper? You can use the `<image>` to embed the images and `<a>` to link to somewhere.

At this point (with all the small SVG images already made) the only problem is to put them back together in the right size and position. Maybe you could go one step back in the process and have a look at the source files and see if the sizing/positioning can be solved there.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <a href="#1">
    <image href="https://svgur.com/i/gUR.svg" width="40" x="30"/>
  </a>
  <a href="#2">
    <image href="https://svgur.com/i/gUQ.svg" width="38" x="58" y="5" />
  </a>
  <a href="#3">
    <image href="https://svgur.com/i/gTa.svg" width="33" x="64" y="38" />
  </a>
<svg>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use an SVG inside an SVG, and set positioning?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I guess that would work the same way, and you would have less requests to the server. But I think that it is a problem that all the images are already split up. They are probably the same image in Illustrator, so the entire SVG could be exported from there without having the issue with the positioning afterwords.

Comment: (sorry, on boss time) How about a circle with pathLength 6 and (instant)animate the 6 pieces into position?

Comment: Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66975279/how-to-place-menu-items-on-a-curved-bar/66984054#66984054) but on a circle

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Yes, something like that. The problem with the images in this case is that they are already rotated and they have different sizes.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way of achieving this is by centring all the images in the middle and then use `transform` to place them where you need.

So starting with:

```
transform: rotate(0deg) translate(10em) rotate(0deg);
```

And increasing the `rotate` and `translate` per image

---

Since the actual position does not seems to be aligned in your example, I'd just spaced them evenly:

```css
.image-holder {
  position: relative;
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5em auto 0;
}
.image-holder > img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -3em;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
}
.image-holder > img:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(10em) rotate(0deg);
}
.image-holder > img:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(10em) rotate(-45deg);
}
.image-holder > img:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(10em) rotate(-90deg);
}
.image-holder > img:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(135deg) translate(10em) rotate(-135deg);
}
.image-holder > img:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(10em) rotate(-180deg);
}
.image-holder > img:nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotate(225deg) translate(10em) rotate(-225deg);
}
.image-holder > img:nth-of-type(7) {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(10em) rotate(-270deg);
}
.image-holder > img:nth-of-type(8) {
  transform: rotate(315deg) translate(10em) rotate(-315deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
  <img class='slice' src="https://placehold.jp/50x50.png?text=1" alt="">
  <img class='slice' src="https://placehold.jp/50x50.png?text=2" alt="">
  <img class='slice' src="https://placehold.jp/50x50.png?text=3" alt="">
  <img class='slice' src="https://placehold.jp/50x50.png?text=4" alt="">
  <img class='slice' src="https://placehold.jp/50x50.png?text=5" alt="">
  <img class='slice' src="https://placehold.jp/50x50.png?text=6" alt="">
  <img class='slice' src="https://placehold.jp/50x50.png?text=7" alt="">
  <img class='slice' src="https://placehold.jp/50x50.png?text=8" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also construct one SVG image with all the content. It takes some time, but this is a start:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1700 1700" font-size="40" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">
  <path id="p1" d="M -348.917 -763.913 q 14.3 -6.534 28.831 -12.534 q 22.177 -9.132 44.8 -16.984 A 842.35 842.35 0 0 1 50.923 -838.5 c 1.469 0.086 2.91 0.181 4.37 0.284 c 4.405 0.3 8.8 0.62 13.2 0.984 A 841.9 841.9 0 0 1 299.932 -784.6 c 2.061 0.793 4.12 1.585 6.19 2.4 c 4.175 1.61 8.315 3.293 12.446 4.993 q 15.309 6.24 30.333 13.118 l -91.961 190.994 a 22.714 22.714 0 0 0 5.246 26.632 a 22.349 22.349 0 0 0 5.349 3.6 c 5.911 2.846 13.752 2.6 20.985 -0.662 a 38.549 38.549 0 1 1 -21.492 44.635 c -1.957 -7.69 -6.657 -13.971 -12.568 -16.817 a 22.372 22.372 0 0 0 -6.148 -1.939 a 22.708 22.708 0 0 0 -24.081 12.49 L 119.907 -288.482 a 308.9 308.9 0 0 0 -113.857 -24.055 c -1.361 -0.034 -2.729 -0.048 -4.08 -0.055 l -2.658 -0.015 c -3.38 0.015 -6.77 0.093 -10.131 0.205 A 308.721 308.721 0 0 0 -119.907 -288.455 L -209.1 -473.642 a 7.645 7.645 0 0 1 6.411 -10.964 a 71.13 71.13 0 1 0 -23.886 -139.181 a 73.715 73.715 0 0 0 -10.414 4.065 a 70.73 70.73 0 0 0 -22.556 17.064 a 7.627 7.627 0 0 1 -12.577 -1.816 Z" />
  <a href="#1">
    <use href="#p1" transform="translate(850 850) rotate(0)" fill="#eeaa23"/>
    <text fill="white" x="850" y="850" transform="translate(0 -500)">Techniek</text>
  </a>
  <a href="#2">
    <g transform="translate(850 850) rotate(51.43)">
      <use href="#p1" fill="#c09a2d"/>
      <g fill="white" transform="translate(0 -500) rotate(-51.43)">
        <text>(Aard)Warmte-</text>
        <text transform="translate(20 50)">projecten</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </a>
  <a href="#3">
    <g transform="translate(850 850) rotate(102.86)">
      <use href="#p1" fill="#75813d"/>
      <g fill="white" transform="translate(0 -500) rotate(-102.86)">
        <text>(Duurzame)</text>
        <text transform="translate(20 50)">Energiezaken</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </a>
  <a href="#4">
    <g transform="translate(850 850) rotate(154.29)">
      <use href="#p1" fill="#eeaa23"/>
    </g>
  </a>
  <a href="#5">
    <g transform="translate(850 850) rotate(205.71)">
      <use href="#p1" fill="#eeaa23"/>
    </g>
  </a>
  <a href="#6">
   <g transform="translate(850 850) rotate(257.14)">
      <use href="#p1" fill="#eeaa23"/>
    </g>
  </a>
  <a href="#7">
    <g transform="translate(850 850) rotate(308.57)">
      <use href="#p1" fill="#eeaa23"/>
    </g>
  </a>
<svg>
```